# Where can I find a list of the PowerShell's atributes?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I was just wondering, it would be cool to know all the atributes used in powershell commands so i can list them all and be more efficient when I have to query something, instead of looking online for the command I need.
I'm probably explaining too bad, I mean this options:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '*ldap*'" -Properties * | select Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,PasswordLastSet,EmailAddress,Enabled
```

The options that go after the option **-Filter**... Name, SamAccountName, enabled, etc.

I would be really grateful, thanks in advice ü

Comment: Are you looking for a given command's _parameters_, such as `-Filter`, or are you looking for the _properties_ of the objects that `Get-ADUser` returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the options for a command, use `Get-Help «command» -detailed` or look up the command on-line at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com). To find out what methods and properties an object returned from a command might have, pipe the object to `Get-Member`.